# android studio(java y volley) Insertar lista de items de recyclerview en mysql

Tags: php, java, mysql, android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo una app en android studio de venta de productos, al finalizar la venta tengo que almacenar los datos en tablas relacionadas entre ventas y detalle_ventas en mysql. el id_venta tiene un relación con detalle_ventas.

Tabla ventas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla detalle de ventas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los productos que voy a guardar los muestro en un recyclerview(tengo tres items o productos) pero al darle al boton de realizar venta solo me guarda el ultimo item y duplicado como se ve en las tablas y necesito  que me guarde los tres productos con el ultimo id registrado en la tabla venta, por favor me ayudan a resolver este problema, muchas gracias por su tiempo.

este es mi archivo php.

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php'; 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $fecha_venta = $_POST["fecha_venta"];
    $total_precio_venta = $_POST["total_precio_venta"];
    $estado=$_POST["estado"];
    
    $cantidad_producto=$_POST["cantidad_producto"];
    $precio_unitario=$_POST["precio_unitario"];
    $sub_precio=$_POST["sub_precio"];
    $estado_detalle=$_POST["estado_detalle"];
    $id_producto=$_POST["id_producto"];
        
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ventas(fecha_venta,total_precio_venta,estado)VALUES('$fecha_venta','$total_precio_venta','$estado')";

    if ($conexion->query($sql)) {

        $id_venta_r = $conexion->insert_id;

        $sql_detalle = "INSERT INTO detalle_ventas(cantidad_producto,precio_unitario,sub_precio,estado_detalle,id_venta,id_producto)VALUES('$cantidad_producto','$precio_unitario','$sub_precio','$estado_detalle',$id_venta_r,'$id_producto')";

        $conexion->query($sql_detalle);
  
    mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_detalle) or die (mysqli_error($conexion)); 
    
    
}
```

y este es el activity de donde inserto la venta

```
public void registrarVenta(){
    //***** fecha *****
    Date date=new Date();
    String fecha=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
    //*****************
    int estado=1;
    //***** precio total ********
    float precioTotal=0;
    for (int i=0;i<listaCarrito.size();i++){
        Carrito sub_total_car=listaCarrito.get(i);
        float price=sub_total_car.subTotal();
        precioTotal=precioTotal+price;
    }

    String url="https://192.168.1.100/BDcarrito/registrarVenta.php";
    float finalPrecioTotal = precioTotal;

    stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            String cant;
            String precio_u;
            int estado_detalle=1;
            String id_producto;
            Float sub;

            Map<String,String> parametros=new HashMap<String,String>();
            for (int i=0;i<listaCarrito.size();i++){
                cant=listaCarrito.get(i).getNum_items().toString();
                precio_u=listaCarrito.get(i).getPrecio().toString();
                sub=listaCarrito.get(i).getPrecio()*listaCarrito.get(i).getNum_items();
                id_producto=listaCarrito.get(i).getId_producto().toString();
                parametros.put("fecha_venta",fecha);
                parametros.put("total_precio_venta", String.valueOf(finalPrecioTotal));
                parametros.put("estado", String.valueOf(estado));

                parametros.put("cantidad_producto",cant);
                parametros.put("precio_unitario",precio_u);
                parametros.put("sub_precio", String.valueOf(sub));
                parametros.put("estado_detalle", String.valueOf(estado_detalle));
                parametros.put("id_producto",id_producto);

            }
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    request.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Ya intentaste hacer un debug?

Comment: En el Activity tienes que mandar los datos como array y en PHP también debes recorrer dicho array para insertar las diferentes filas. Te está insertando el último precisamente por eso, porque al no meter los datos en un array solamente se queda con el último.